# Specifying gem from github does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle

If I write this in my Gemfile

```
gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise', branch: 'master'
```

I get the following error:

```
SystemStackError: stack level too deep.
An error occurred while installing devise (4.0.0.rc2), and Bundler cannot continue.
```

But if I specify this in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'devise', '4.0.0.rc2'
```

It works correctly, any idea why specifying the gem from github is not working properly? It happen with all the gems that I tried and I need specify another gem from github because the version has not been updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `Gemfile`. Then run `bundle install`.

```
gem 'devise', git: 'git@github.com:plataformatec/devise.git', branch: 'master'
```

Hopefully it will work. Thank you